# How to make sure that every 3x3 block contains values in Sudoku

Tags: java, arrays, nested, sudoku

I want to check a whole Sudoku table if all the blocks got the 9 values or not but I was able to check only the first block and I need to check the other 8 blocks how?

```
 public static boolean checkSubs(int[][] p) {
       int[] nums = new int[9];
       int x=0, temp;
        for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
           for (int j=0; j<3; j++) {
             temp = p[i][j];
             for ( int m=0; m<nums.length; m++)
             if ( nums[m]==temp ) return false; 
             nums[x++]=temp; }
             return true; }
```

Comment: Do the same thing for 3 to 6 and 6 to 9. And fix your indentation.

Comment: won't check all blocks still

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your checkSubsMethod.

- Add i and j of the top left corner of sudoku subblock (e.g (0,0), (0,3),... (3,0), (3,3)... (6,3),(6,6)).
- Use set to check does the value already used or not. The add() method of Set class return `true` if value doesn't in the set and `false` if value already added to the set.

And when you generalise your method you can use it for fields of any size. In your case size is 9x9, here is the example

```
public static boolean checkSubs(int[][] p, int topI, int topJ) {
    Set<Integer> nums = new HashSet<>();
    for (int i = topI; i < topI + 3; i++) {
        for (int j = topJ; j < topJ + 3; j++) {
            if (!nums.add(p[i][j])) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] sudoku = {
        {1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3},
        {4,5,6,4,5,6,4,5,6},
        {7,8,9,7,8,9,7,8,9},
        {1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3},
        {4,5,6,4,5,6,4,5,6},
        {7,8,9,7,8,9,7,8,9},
        {1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3},
        {4,5,6,4,5,6,4,5,6},
        {7,8,9,7,8,9,7,8,9}};

    for (int i = 0; i < sudoku.length;i += 3){
        for (int j = 0; j<sudoku[0].length; j += 3){
            if (!checkSubs(sudoku, i, j)){
                System.out.println("DUPLICATED VALUES FOUND!");
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("OK!!");

}
```

The output for this case will be `OK!!`

If you change the input like this

```
 int[][] sudoku = {
 {3,3,3,1,2,3,1,2,3},
 {4,5,6,4,5,6,4,5,6},
 {7,8,9,7,8,9,7,8,9},
 {1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3},
 {4,5,6,4,5,6,4,5,6},
 {7,8,9,7,8,9,7,8,9},
 {1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3},
 {4,5,6,4,5,6,4,5,6},
 {7,8,9,7,8,9,7,8,9}};
```

The output will be `DUPLICATED VALUES FOUND!`

You can modify this example for your purposes in future.